# CMake MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist

Tags: c++, cmake, msbuild, ninja

I need to build my CMake based project under MSVC **2013** and MSVC **2019**.

With MSVC **2019** using Ninja generator I build it successfully with following commands:

```
cmake -S . -B build -GNinja "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release"
cmake --build build --target all
```

On MSVC **2013** I have no Ninja available, so I tried the following:

```
cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release
cmake --build build --target all
```

Anyway I am getting following error and nothing is built:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: all.vcxproj
```

Any idea how to build it without ninja? (I cannot install it, since I am building it on a build server.)

Comment: The target is called `ALL_BUILD` for Visual Studio generators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In contrast to other generators (like `Makefiles` or `Ninja`) CMake does not generate an `all` target for `Visual Studio` solution but an `ALL_BUILD` target.

So `cmake --build build --target ALL_BUILD --config Release` should succeed.